# Using ffmpeng in swift code using PythonKit

Tags: python, swift, swift-pythonkit

I have a python script that uses `ffmpeng`. I installed it using `brew install ffmpeg`. If I run the python script on python IDE it runs perfectly.

But I wanted to run this python script on my macOS app, so using PythonKit I tried running it:

```
static func make_audio(dict: [String: String]) {
        let sys = Python.import("sys")
        let dirPath = "/Users/seungjunlee/PycharmProjects/pythonProject8"
        sys.path.append(dirPath)
        let Media = Python.import("audio")
        Media.make_audio(PythonObject(dict))
    }
```

But if I run above function it keep saying cannot find `ffmpeng`. So I installed ffmpeng again in current directory.(macOS app project). But I'm still getting error.

I already spent several hours fixing `can't find ffmpeng` bug appearing when running the python script on Python IDE. The solution was installing it using command `brew install ffmpeg`. But now it appearing again when I try to run the script in swift code.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks.